# Radiogroup set Checked Extjs 4.0

Tags: extjs4

I have the following code:

```
        items: [{
            boxLabel: 'yes',
            name: 'sameName', 
            inputValue: '1'

        },{
            boxLabel: 'no', 
            name: 'sameName',
            inputValue: '0',
            checked: true
        }]
```

default 'no' is checked, now i want to un-check it and check item (grammatically) where input value is 1, I tried many things but nothing work.

Comment: have you tried: `group.setValue({ sameName: 1 })`?

Comment: yes it works, also works this: radioGroup.items.items[0].setValue(true);
but this items is render many times and this is my problem..

Comment: in order to solve my problem i used combo, chekbox problem was that there have one names(one checkbox was renderd many times).

Answer (score 0):

Try this when your app is loading (its easier)

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.Checkbox, { inputValue: '1',  uncheckedValue: '0'});
```